# No alerts for Webhooks disablement in Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops

We have webhooks firing in Azure Devops which push data to a logic app which in turn performs some actions. Sometimes due to too many requests at once or a multitude of other reasons, the logic apps fail. After a certain number of successive failures, the webhooks are disabled automatically. See [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/service-hooks/troubleshoot?view=azure-devops)

There is no notification of webhooks disablement sent out.

Is there a way to notify when the webhooks are disabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting just if someone else is searching for fixing this.

We have created a logic app which runs daily and checks the status of the service hooks using the [Service hooks API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/hooks/subscriptions/replace-subscription?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0). If disabled due to any reason, it just enables it back and sends an email to support intimating them of this.

Works like a charm!